# Импорт модели из субдиректории

Tags: django

Безуспешно пытаюсь импортировать модели из субдиректории. В результате получаю ошибку о том, что модель не имеет атрибут object. Пожалуйста, помогите решить проблему.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка в синтаксисе джанги:
Sending.objects.filter.....

Comment: Спасибо большое. Совсем глаз замылился..